# HDP android implementation

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluez

I`m trying to link my Android phone(xperia sp) with installed HDP app(sink) to laptop with Ubuntu 14 and Antidote(sample_bt_agent).

HDP application: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/512ea9b6f8cc75ec74a7ab8d1c38dec201667f1e/samples/BluetoothHDP

Antidote:
http://oss.signove.com/index.php/Antidote:_IEEE_11073-20601_stack

And there is an error on Ubuntu:   *connection
initiation error: No matching MDEP found*

And debug message from Eclipse ADT: *Method "CreateChannel" with signature "os" on interface "org.bluez.HealthDevice" doesn't exist*

Any ideas how to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device codes not the same in android code and in Antidote. In Antidote pulse-oximeter is 0x0190, but in android it must be 0x1004.